# NextJS cookies() function cause page refresh / trpc always fetches entire route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, trpc

Should a cookies().set() function call cause full page refresh in new Next 14? In the chart component, every interval change requests new data so I thought I would do this server-side, until now it refetched the data and it was fine but since yesterday it started to cause a full page refresh and reload of my other component which is on this same route but is more expensive and loads much longer. The docs only say that

```
Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time.
```

But this does not necessarily mean that having this call in my component would reload the entire page right?

And also if you will I have a concern about trpc that I use, when I make a call to my backend for any route in the network tab I always see a fetch where it fails to load the response and payload in case of a component with this cookies() call is the value of the cookie i set or some gibberish from next i believe

```
1: "tkJNa2edO1ReSBFeTtF3/ylWv+2A46cEY5LLkcOCkYgMnfkWeX/SMd+/CCIPBH4W9IettDZ1H0IM9xHzjjKJ4w28FevcMDLnMkHF0H7TymCoxFH04w=="
2_$ACTION_REF_1: 
2_$ACTION_1:1: ["$@2"]
2_$ACTION_1:0: {"id":"8ad85c6f04f4b5912851a1a1b7731332e1b2753c","bound":"$@1"}
2_$ACTION_1:2: "tWfv6x4N8OQpm2utvGMwGwQAHv8WRKnPZYXCJEXaI224Bve7D+IVjbkA9F+v9u5hdU2xmwNmx8usNLY5DsewZqmpDRXD1X7vzsM33CUZSs8wsg9DVA=="
0: ["$@1","$K2"]
```

This is my component:

```
export async function TradingCharts({ symbol }: D3ChartProps) {
  const interval = (cookies().get('interval')?.value ?? '1d') as KlineInterval;
  const candlesticksPromise = client.binance.candlestick.query({
    symbol,
    interval,
  });
  const lastTradePromise = client.binance.lastTrade.query({ symbol });
  const [candlesticks, recentTrade] = await Promise.all([candlesticksPromise, lastTradePromise]);

  const handleIntervalChange = async (interval: KlineInterval) => {
    'use server';
    cookies().set('interval', interval, { maxAge: 0 });
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <IntervalButtons changeInterval={handleIntervalChange} currentInterval={interval} />
      <CandlestickChart
        {...{ symbol, candlesticks, interval, recentTrade: parseFloat(recentTrade ?? '0') }}
        key={interval}
      />
    </section>
  );
}
```

and just in case this is how I initialize trpc in Nextjs

```
export const client = createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({
  links: [
    splitLink({
      condition: (op) => op.type === 'subscription',
      true: wsLink({
        client: createWSClient({
          url: 'ws://localhost:7000',
        }),
      }),
      false: httpBatchLink({
        url: 'http://localhost:7000',
        fetch(url, options) {
          return fetch(url, {
            ...options,
            credentials: 'include',
            cache: 'no-store',
          });
        },
      }),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, what you want here is to call the Server Action, but set the cookie client-side:

```js
onIntervalChange={async (interval) => {
    // NOTE: at this point I still can't tell if you need to use
    // a React transition, there are no official answers on this
    const data = await yourServerActionThatGetsData(interval)
    setState(data)
   // CLIENT-SIDE cookie setting code, using smth like react-cookies
    cookies.set("interval", interval)
    
}}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your use case

Comment: Yes you are right , thank you for making that point.